# Django Deserialization

Tags: python, django, serialization

I am getting the following error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "../tests.py", line 92, in test_single_search
>
> for return_obj in serializers.deserialize("json",response, ensure_ascii=False):
>   File "/Library/Python/2.6/site-packages/django/core/serializers/json.py",
>   line 38, in Deserializer
>       for obj in PythonDeserializer(simplejson.load(stream),
>   **options):   File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/json/**init**.py",
>   line 264, in load
>       return loads(fp.read(), AttributeError: 'HttpResponse' object
>   has no attribute 'read'

In views.py the serialization works correctly:

```
resultsjson = serializers.serialize("json", results, ensure_ascii=False)
return HttpResponse(resultsjson, mimetype = 'application/json')
```

However, when I try to process the result in my calling method in test.py:

```
response = self.client.get("/path/?query=testValue")
for return_obj in serializers.deserialize("json", response, ensure_ascii=False):
      print return_obj
```

I get the above error. Has anyone come across the same error. I am using Django 1.2 (latest version from svn) and it appears to be using the in-built simplejson serializser.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to use `response.content` rather than just `response` in your call to `deserialize`. The response object is an instance of HttpResponse, but has an attribute of `content` which contains the actual JSON in this case.

Comment: yes, try `serializers.deserialize("json", response.content, ensure_ascii=False)` as Daniel suggested

Comment: for newer Django versions use ```json```. so it would be ```json.loads(response.content)```